# Why image and text are overlapping in my dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I am trying to insert logo and then below that i want to have text.
Text and my logo are overlapping. Below is my code

```
<div id="dialog-confirm">    
    <p>
        <span style ="float: left; margin: 0 7px 50px 0; width: 50px; height: 37px;">
            <img src="images/logo.png" alt="splash" />
        </span>
    </p>     
    <p>
        <strong>Please Note:</strong> My Text here
    </p>

    <ul>
        <li>point1</li>
        <li>point2</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle or jsbin?

Comment: Simple, use clear:both after span.. see https://jsfiddle.net/ey3sc9jf/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your image and text are aligned because your `span`is floatting left.
Remove  `float`and it must be done ;)

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8v1d5ckb/)